# Adding Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, select, arithmetic-expressions

I have this equation in a select query

> Monitoring Fees"+"CCN Fees"+"WkRpt Fees"+"MonRpt Fees"+"Client Dashboard Fees"+"Take
>   Control Servers Fees"+"Patch Management Servers Fees"+"Remote Background Servers Fees"
>   as "Total Capped Server Fees"

A problem I am seeing is that it will only add if there is value in each of the columns but I need it to add even if there is no data.

For remote background server, fees do not kick in until September of 2013. So Total capped server fees equation isn't adding add the others until there is values for everything so it is starting in september 2013 instead of for all years.

Comment: Add Column "Remote Background Servers Fees" with a Null Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the columns are returning `NULL`. You need to use `ISNULL` to return 0 instead of `NULL`. For example:

```
ISNULL("Monitoring Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("CCN Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("WkRpt Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("MonRpt Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("Client Dashboard Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("Take Control Servers Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("Patch Management Servers Fees", 0) + 
ISNULL("Remote Background Servers Fees", 0) as "Total Capped Server Fees"
```

I am assuming you are using SQL Server.

If you are using MySQL then the equivalent function is `IFNULL`. For example:

```
IFNULL("Monitoring Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("CCN Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("WkRpt Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("MonRpt Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("Client Dashboard Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("Take Control Servers Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("Patch Management Servers Fees", 0) + 
IFNULL("Remote Background Servers Fees", 0) as "Total Capped Server Fees"
```